# Sometimes wrong result when executing query

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
photos(objectID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, photo varbinary(max))
```

I have ASP.NET WebForms application that does the following. When received query string of correct format:

```
~/script.aspx?identifier=a123-b456789....
```

It issues the following query:

```
SELECT photo FROM photos where objectID='a123-b456789...'
```

After receiving binary object my application displays it. The problem is that the same query may result in correct image and may not. No exceptions are thrown. What this could be? I'm using no transactions.

Comment: You sure `SELECT Photo FROM photos where objectID='a123-b456789...' ` is the same as `SELECT photo FROM photos where objectID='a123-b456789...'`

Comment: Sure, the columns name are the same in query as they are in database table definition.

Comment: What does "may not" mean? Do you get the wrong image, no image, a broken image, a half-rendered image?

Comment: No image. If save this file, it's empty

Comment: Maybe ContentType or charset problem... What browser? What type of image? What's the error? At DB level, ASP.NET level or browser level?

Comment: Run a SQL Trace (with SQL Profiler) to see the exact query that hits the database.  My guess is it's not always what you think it is.

Comment: @AndreaColleoni the same issue in all browsers. Image format is jpeg. Headers are set in ashx handler correctly. As I said, no error, just image is not loading. And this happens to the same query.

Comment: Why do you store images in your database? It is VERY inefficient and generally a bad idea.
Do I understand it correctly that page refresh may or may not result in correctly displayed image or an error at random?
In this case you should check what else is different - page variables, something else. I would suggest you create a test page that will have ONLY a call to get the data and an img tag to display it. If that page does NOT work either than you have some strange DB connection configuration problems.

Comment: When testing the above query in SQL management studio, the results also differ from time to time.

Comment: How are you generating `objectID`? The chances of a collision on a GUID are incredibly small, but if you are doing something to generate it yourself, there may be an issue there. What are the results of `SELECT objectID, COUNT(*) FROM photos GROUP BY objectID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`?

Comment: Nothing was returned. And using profiler I have found out the query is fine. Maybe that's some locking issues? For example when the query is executed twice at the same time?